# Flatten a JSON document using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm considering the following array of JSON objects:

```
[
  {
    "index": "index1",
    "type": "type1",
    "id": "id1",
    "fields": {
      "deviceOs": [
        "Android"
      ],
      "deviceID": [
        "deviceID1"
      ],
      "type": [
        "type"
      ],
      "country": [
        "DE"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "index": "index2",
    "type": "type2",
    "id": "id2",
    "fields": {
      "deviceOs": [
        "Android"
      ],
      "deviceID": [
        "deviceID2"
      ],
      "type": [
        "type"
      ],
      "country": [
        "US"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

and I would like to flatten it to get:

```
[
  {
    "index": "index1",
    "type": "type",
    "id": "id1",
    "deviceOs": "Android",
    "deviceID": "deviceID1",
    "country": "DE"
  },
  {
    "index": "index2",
    "type": "type",
    "id": "id2",
    "deviceOs": "Android",
    "deviceID": "deviceID2",
    "country": "US"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to work with `jq` but I fail to flatten the `"fields"`. How should I do it? At the moment I'm interested in command-line tools, but I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: I am upvoting this question about "un-arraying" elements to a certain depth, but the ambiguous title may lead you here when you are trying to "REALLY flatten a json document using jq"; if that's you, as it was me, check out ```paths``` and consider the product of ```[paths(scalars) as $path | { ($path | map(tostring) | join("_")): getpath($path) } ][]```

Comment: @nik.shornikov slight improvement, replacing `[]` in the end with `| add` gives one object with all flattened path/value pairs: `[paths(scalars) as $path | { ($path | map(tostring) | join("_")): getpath($path) } ] | add`

Comment: @nik.shornikov This is exactly what I was looking for. For future searchers, the above code snippet will un-nest all keys in an object to arbitrary depth, with the join character as separator.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This one was a tricky one to craft.

```
map
(
    with_entries(select(.key != "fields"))
    +
    (.fields | with_entries(.value = .value[0]))
)
```

Let's break it down and explain the bits of it

1. For every item in the array...

   ```
   map(...)
   ```
2. Create a new object containing the values for all except the `fields` property.

   ```
   with_entries(select(.key != "fields"))
   ```
3. Combine that with...

   ```
   +
   ```
4. Each of the `fields` projecting each of the values to the first item of each array

   ```
   (.fields | with_entries(.value = .value[0]))
   ```

Comment: Great answer. Tiny part I would add is for a join since hard-coded list indices make me worry about missing stuff. `with_entries(.value = (.value| join(",")))`  https://jqplay.org/s/2mY6yus7Mz

Comment: `with_entries(select(.key != "fields"))` could be replaced with `del(.fields)`, shortening the program somewhat.

Answer (score 28):

There's a tool called [`gron`](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron) and you can pipe that json in, to get something like this.

```sh
$ gron document.json
json = [];
json[0] = {};
json[0].fields = {};
json[0].fields.country = [];
json[0].fields.country[0] = "DE";
json[0].fields.deviceID = [];
json[0].fields.deviceID[0] = "deviceID1";
json[0].fields.deviceOs = [];
json[0].fields.deviceOs[0] = "Android";
json[0].fields.type = [];
json[0].fields.type[0] = "type";
json[0].id = "id1";
json[0].index = "index1";
json[0].type = "type1";
json[1] = {};
json[1].fields = {};
json[1].fields.country = [];
json[1].fields.country[0] = "US";
json[1].fields.deviceID = [];
json[1].fields.deviceID[0] = "deviceID2";
json[1].fields.deviceOs = [];
json[1].fields.deviceOs[0] = "Android";
json[1].fields.type = [];
json[1].fields.type[0] = "type";
json[1].id = "id2";
json[1].index = "index2";
json[1].type = "type2";
```

Comment: This is awesome! This answer works better for me, because it essentially does recursion down any number of levels. E.g. here `deviceID[.] = \"(.+)\";$` becomes a grep expression that finds the "leaves" in a whole tree of output with varying depth. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this filter:

```
[.[] | {index: .index, type: .type, id: .id, deviceOs: .fields.deviceOs[],deviceID: .fields.deviceID[],country: .fields.country[]}]
```

You can test here [https://jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/UTm4HqX0b6k)

Answer (score 6):

Here are some variations that start by merging .fields into the containing object with + and then flattening the array elements.  First we take care of .fields with

```
  .[]
| . + .fields
| del(.fields)
```

that leaves us with objects which look like

```
{
  "index": "index1",
  "type": [
    "type"
  ],
  "id": "id1",
  "deviceOs": [
    "Android"
  ],
  "deviceID": [
    "deviceID1"
  ],
  "country": [
    "DE"
  ]
}
```

then we can flatten the keys multiple ways. 
One way is to use **with_entries**

```
| with_entries( .value = if .value|type == "array" then .value[0] else .value end )
```

another way is to use **reduce** and **setpath**

```
| . as $v
| reduce keys[] as $k (
    {};
    setpath([$k]; if $v[$k]|type != "array" then $v[$k] else $v[$k][0] end)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the @jq170727 anwser:

```
jq 'map(. + (.fields | with_entries(.value |= .[])) | del(.fields))'
```

(assuming no field inside `.fields` is itself called `.fields`).

The `|with_entries(.value|=.[])` part is to flatten the value arrays in `.fields` -- beware only the first item is preserved. `.value|=join(", ")` could be used to join multiple string values into one.