# jq - how to select nested objects in a single array

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file with multiple objects within multiple arrays, like below

```
[
  [
    {
      "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
      "account": "12344",
      "az": "ca-central-1a"
    },
    {
      "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
      "account": "12344",
      "az": "ca-central-1b"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
      "account": "12344",
      "az": "us-east-1d"
    },
    {
      "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
      "account": "12344",
      "az": "us-east-1d"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "instance_id": "i-35343453453",
      "account": "12344",
      "az": "eu-central-1a"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want the output to be a single array with all the nested objects, like below. Using the JSON input above, how do you use jq to produce the following output?

```
[
{
  "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
  "account": "12344",
  "az": "ca-central-1a"
},
{
  "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
  "account": "12344",
  "az": "ca-central-1b"
},
{
  "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
  "account": "12344",
  "az": "us-east-1d"
},
{
  "instance_id": "i-35345353453",
  "account": "12344",
  "az": "us-east-1d"
},
{
  "instance_id": "i-35343453453",
  "account": "12344",
  "az": "eu-central-1a"
}
]
```

How to get this done in JQ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698188/flatten-a-json-document-using-jq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten a JSON document using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698188/flatten-a-json-document-using-jq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `flatten` filter. See demo with your data: https://jqplay.org/s/kBxBJLxDKH

You can use it in a command like: `jq flatten input_file`.

Answer (score 0):

`[ .[][] ]` works for your example (go down two levels from the root and put everything found into an array), or perhaps `[ .. | objects ]`, which is insensitive to the depth of the array nesting (but does assume that none of your objects contain sub-objects... it just finds all objects at any depth).

Comment: [`add` does the same](https://jqplay.org/s/Jir6mSds8N) with less code.